# Code not able to run correctly for even 300 char Inputs

Tags: c

This is a code for finding the frequency of digits in an string input.which is char array as in case of c.But it is falling when i tried large inputs.

I know there might be something wrong while the conversion of char into int but i cant understand that at what exactly.I know the different approach which exactly solve this problem but i just wanna know what is wrong with this code as it seems to be fine ig.

```
int main() {

    char a[1001];
    scanf("%s",a);
    int arr[10];
    for(int i=48;i<=57;i++){
       arr[i]=0;
    }
    int count=0,j=0;
    while(j<strlen(a)){
      //printf("%c",a[j]);
      if(a[j]>='0' && a[j]<='9'){
        arr[a[j]]++;
      }
      j++;
    }
    //printf("\n");
    for(int i=48;i<=57;i++){
       printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    //printf("\n%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

> A sample input for eg:-->
>   1p69436y8983382u3k820p304507ct815505m68m2ot810224tmoh09f2915dxt972mp3fs58mng9w04c211i17z9z3v975awx9281g9973m33z54t4095408wy1851x3756031586732hxg2te09k11l166789qj9366m7uu550en6910i209f6g081d4247uz6f913270g8l9859lrf325660x5d64016d4784j5688gf4560977279r08242191ste332341q7010ra20f505105mhqg35re342er61200083c9cp9u625e2kvq919go1770097ap485428j1046582g0p71v6j34u5146069x750454v6013f19ye864gr5yi00475304o914a608624664170j6d1d0601er4015285j205268k873hw260209n5g093y3jpdr75574tti0h9161792y70816614sl1tarmj9iz3t1280h91u91k1c984r511644t19j1qvnuuku74g68ont9g7775u3gx74169uf477925236z049386uk12h1w011267x2kdyp49czz532263c7d396nw9917ee166e53803co80752008j1q12

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT:-->56 58 43 37 40 43 47 39 37 48

my code output:-->10 11 10 13 7 12 5 7 12 12
```

Comment: In `arr[i]=0` you are writting outside of the bounds of the array, your space is from `arr[0]` to `arr[9]` but you write from `arr[48]` to `arr[57]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the array holding the result from the ASCII values of the digits - they are not related. Since `for(int i=48;i<=57;i++)` writes out of bounds of the array, just forget about using ASCII values. You can zero-initialize the array as intended with a simple `int arr[10] = {0};`.

Similarly, you can convert from a digit in ASCII format to an integer value by doing `a[i] - '0'`.

Meaning that your loops can be simplified and reduced to this:

```
int arr[10] = {0};
int length = strlen(a);
for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
  if(a[i]>='0' && a[i]<='9')
  {
    int val = a[i] - '0';
    arr[val]++;
  }
}
```

The check `a[i]>='0' && a[i]<='9'` can in turn be replaced with `isdigit(a[i])`, from ctype.h.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int arr[10];
> for(int i=48;i<=57;i++){
>    arr[i]=0;
> }
> ```

Oops ... `arr[48]` does not exist. The indexes of `arr` go from `0` (including `0`) to `9` (excluding `10`)

Try

```
 int arr[10];
 for(int i=48;i<=57;i++){
    arr[i-48]=0;
 }
```

and remember to adjust your code at all places that need adjustment (check all array accesses)

Comment: Or, you know, just do `int arr[10] = {0};` :)

Answer (score -2):

**Solution 1**

Just changing the size of array solves the problem. As it was mentioned before, `arr[48]` does not exist. So, just create array with size of 60 (for ex.): `int arr[60]`

**Solution 2**

In order to conserve memory(i.e. not to waste 45 slots of array) you can do the following:

```
int arr[10];

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
  if(a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9')
    arr[a[i] - '0']++;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

Comment: But you only need 10 elements since the decimal number system only uses 10 digits.

Comment: I know, I was already adding the second solution)

Comment: There's still some minor hiccups. You can initialize the array to zero without a loop, and you shouldn't call strlen repeatedly inside a loop condition. I posted an answer with an alternative code.

Comment: There is always way to optimize code)) I mostly concentrated on solving the problem, but yeah, you are right about your points)